# PHP Todays Date + 1Year

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm putting together a little subscriptions script in PHP which will calculate the expiration date based on todays date and time, but it's giving the result of `0000-00-00 00:00:00` (Datetime)

Here is my code:

```
$added = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$expiry = strtotime('+ 1 year', $added);
```

How can I get this to give me the result of:

```
$added  =  2016-07-30 17-18-33
$expiry =  2017-07-30 17-18-33
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing between getting a timestamp and formatting it. Both need to be done in order to get the output you desire:

```
$now = time();
$added = date("Y-m-d H-i-s", $now);
$expiry = date("Y-m-d H-i-s", strtotime('+ 1 year', $now));
```